# Java battleship program not printing board correctly

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am having a problem with my java battleship program not printing the coordinates that the user enters. When the user guesses a spot on the board its supposed to update the space with an "X" if its a hit, if not then the board remains the same. But when a user guesses wrong on my program, it prints everything except the space where the user guessed. I believe that my else statement where the board updates is the problem, but any modification I did resulted in the board not printing anything.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;



class Battleship {
     public static char randChar(){
         final String alphabet = "ABCDE";
         final int N = alphabet.length();
         char rand;
         Random r = new Random();
         rand = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));
         return rand;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        char[] letters = {' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
        int[] numbers ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[][] ships = new int[7][2];
        char colGuess;
        int rowGuess;
        Boolean boardFlag=false;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //creates the board
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= 5 ; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {                          
                    System.out.print(letters[j] + " ");
                }
                else if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print(numbers[i - 1]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(letters[j] + "" + numbers[i-1]);
                }          
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
        //assigns ships to random spots
        assignShips(ships);
        System.out.println("Enter your guess for the column:");
        colGuess = scan.next().charAt(0);
        //converts to uppercase
        colGuess = Character.toUpperCase(colGuess);
        System.out.println("Enter your guess for the row:");
        rowGuess = scan.nextInt();
        //shows player what they entered
        System.out.println("you entered: " + (char) colGuess + rowGuess);
        //calls method to check for a hit
        fire(colGuess, rowGuess, ships);
        boardFlag = fire(colGuess, rowGuess, ships);
        System.out.println(boardFlag);
        //updates the board
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= 5 ; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.print(letters[j] + " ");
                }
                else if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.print(numbers[i - 1]);
                }
                else {
                    if(letters[j] == colGuess && numbers[i - 1] == rowGuess) {
                        if(boardFlag==true) {
                            System.out.print(" " + "X");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print(letters[j] + "" + numbers[i - 1]);
                    }
                }          
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void assignShips(int[][] ships) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int ship = 0; ship < 7; ship++) {
            ships[ship][0] = randChar();
            ships[ship][1] = random.nextInt(5);
            //gives location of ships, for testing purposes
            System.out.print("Ship:" + (ship+1)+ " is located at"+(char)ships[ship][0]+ships[ship][1]+"\n");
        }
    }

    //checks user input to see if we have a hit
    public static Boolean fire(char colGuess, int rowGuess, int[][] ships) {
        Boolean hitFlag=false;
        for(int ship = 0; ship < ships.length; ship++){
            if(colGuess ==ships[ship][0] && rowGuess == ships[ship][1]){
                hitFlag=true;
            }
        }
        if(hitFlag == true) {
            System.out.println("we hit em at "+(char)colGuess+rowGuess+" chief!");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("sorry chief we missed em");
        }
        return hitFlag;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit of proper formatting goes a long way.

Comment: It wouldnt surprise me if your source code looks the same in your own file. And it doesn't come as surprise then when you have to turn to other people to be told what your code is doing. Just because it is so hard to read ...

Comment: yea sorry about the formatting its been copy and pasted from various programs on different computers as I was working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not showing up when you miss is because your net telling it to print anything.

```
if(letters[j] == colGuess && numbers[i-1] == rowGuess){
    if(boardFlag==true) {
        System.out.print(" "+"X");
    }
}
```

Your only handling the coordinate the user input if they hit. To fix this you would need an else statement after your `if(boardFlag == true)`to handle printing if you miss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your update board portion of the code because you don't do anything if the guessed location isn't a hit.

```
if(letters[j]==colGuess && numbers[i-1]==rowGuess && boardFlag) {
    System.out.print(" "+"X");
} else {
    System.out.print(letters[j]+""+numbers[i-1]);
}
```

Full Update Portion:

```
//updates the board
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= 5 ; j++){
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.print(letters[j]+" ");
        } else if (j == 0){
            System.out.print(numbers[i-1] );
        } else {
            if(letters[j]==colGuess && numbers[i-1]==rowGuess && boardFlag){
                System.out.print(" "+"X");
            } else {
                System.out.print(letters[j]+""+numbers[i-1]);
            }
        }          
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: so it was just the placement of the else? Because I tried moving it up in the  loop but then i caused it to not print anything.

Comment: Basically you can combine the checking for the boardFlag into the if statement and because of that, you can rearrange your else into the way above. So it's checking if the guess is the same as the current location in the arrays as well as if boardFlag is true and if any of those are false then it prints the board normally like when you were creating it the first time.

Comment: I actually tried putting the boardFlag check in the if statement with the row and column guess, but I must've not been doing it right because it still wasn't outputting correctly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This block (old version):

```
     if(hitFlag==true){
        System.out.println("we hit em at "+(char)colGuess+rowGuess+" chief!");
     } else { 
        System.out.println("sorry chief we missed em");
     }
```

Should be (new version):

```
    if(hitFlag==true){
        System.out.println("we hit em at "+(char)colGuess+rowGuess+" chief!");
    } else { 
        System.out.println("sorry chief we missed em at " + (char)colGuess+rowGuess);
    }
```

this will print:

```
sorry chief we missed em at D3      //D3 is a random possible set of coordinates
```

Rather than:

```
sorry chief we missed em            //Old version
```

So all you have to add is `(char)colGuess+rowGuess`, which prints the coordinates of your previous guess.

---

Comment if you have any questions!

Comment: @bluphantom91 this is a very simple way to do it, It uses no new code, and is very simple.

Comment: @bluphantom91 - I hope this code worked out OK, It worked fine when I tested it on my machine. Please get back to me if it worked